# How to clear out or delete an unnamed widget-pool containing my static class

Tags: widget, pool, progress-4gl, openedge, static-class

I'm working with Progress 10.1c

I have a class that contains both static and non-static methods.

The class is defined with USE-WIDGET-POOL. In the destructor I say "DELETE WIDGET-POOL".

I create an instance of my class, and call a method. The method itself uses one of the static methods of the class. So if I understand it correctly, I will now have the instance of my class in its own unnamed pool, and a separate unnamed widget pool for the static members of the class.

So far so good. But I'm busy debugging and I'm making changes to the code. I recompile and run my test again. Now my non-static members work, but all the static members come from the older version of my class, that is still stored in the pool for static members, which is scoped to the session. In other words, the "DELETE WIDGET-POOL" in my destructor deleted the pool for the instance of the class, but the pool for the static members is still there.

The only way I can get it to load the new version of my class is to log off my session, and log on again. This is quite a mission in our environment. Every time I make a change, I have to stop and start my development environment.

I tried to walk the list of objects in my session, but could not find what I'm looking for. There's a good chance I'm starting at the wrong object, or I'm missing some knowledge of pools and objects in Progress.

Is there any way for me to target that unnamed pool and delete the static "instance" of my class, without destroying my session every time?

Comment: It turns out I am not misunderstanding how this works: The problem here is that the static pool is hidden and it is scoped to the session. So you can't access the pool and you won't see its objects by walking the list of objects, and you have to end the session to delete the pool. There does not seem to be another way.

Comment: I really would like to accept one of the answers for this question, but we have conflicting evidence. My solution works perfectly, tried and tested. But for others it does not work. I need to know why before I can get closure. Does anybody have any ideas? Is this unique to 10.1c? Are there parameters or preferences that could affect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be doable with very little coding. I can use the statement DELETE OBJECT THIS-OBJECT to delete the instance executing that statement. So if it's in a static method, it is the static instance that gets deleted.

```
METHOD STATIC VOID Reload () :
    DELETE OBJECT THIS-OBJECT.
END METHOD.
```

So now when I have a new version of the class, I just use MyClass:Reload(). No need to end my session.

Thanks to [Tim Kuehn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190339/tim-kuehn) for pointing me in the right direction with his suggestion of using a static method to delete the named widget-pool.

---

I have created this example to demonstrate how I got it to work. Below is a simple class with 3 static methods:

```
/* File : rtt/cls/demo.cls */

USING Progress.Lang.*.
ROUTINE-LEVEL ON ERROR UNDO, THROW.

CLASS rtt.cls.demo USE-WIDGET-POOL :

    METHOD STATIC CHARACTER SayHello() :
      RETURN "Good-bye".
    END METHOD.

    METHOD STATIC VOID ShowMessage() :
      MESSAGE "This is the message." VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    END METHOD.

    METHOD STATIC VOID Reload() :
      DELETE OBJECT this-object.
    END METHOD.

END CLASS.
```

I don't know how other people's environments are set up, but in my environment I have to log on to our system to be able to compile and run programs, in other words, I have an active session.

So I compile the file:

```
COMPILE VALUE(SEARCH("rtt/cls/demo.cls")) SAVE.
```

And then I run the following bit in Procedure Editor to test it:

```
USING rtt.cls.*.

demo:ShowMessage().
MESSAGE demo:SayHello().
```

When I run this, I get a message box that says "This is the message.", followed by a message box that says "Good-bye". Exactly as one would expect.

But there's a bug, it's supposed to say "Hello", not "Good-Bye", so I edit my class (I'm only showing the two methods I'm changing:

```
    METHOD STATIC CHARACTER SayHello() :
      RETURN "Hello".
    END METHOD.

    METHOD STATIC VOID ShowMessage() :
      MESSAGE "That was the message." VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    END METHOD.
```

I save my changes, compile it as before, and I run the test again. What messages do you expect to see? I expect to see "This is the message." and "Good-bye", same as before. That's logical, because there is a hidden widget-pool in my current session, and it has an instance of my class loaded (from my first test). It will keep on using this instance until the instance or the pool is destroyed. So I shut down my development environment, log off and then log on again to start up a new session. So far everything is working exactly as expected.

Now I run my test again, and sure enough, I get my new version: the messages are "That was the message" and "Hello".

But now I'm told to add an exclamation after the word "Hello". so I change it:

```
    METHOD STATIC CHARACTER SayHello() :
      RETURN "Hello!".
    END METHOD.
```

I save it and compile it. When I run the test, obviously I will get the older version that says "Hello" without the exclamation. I have to restart my session again before my changes become active. I really don't want to do that again. So I change my test as follows:

```
USING rtt.cls.*.

demo:Reload().

demo:ShowMessage().
MESSAGE demo:SayHello().
```

I run it and voilà, I get my latest changes. I change the message from "That was the message" to "It works!". I save, compile and run my test. What do I see? I see "It works!". No more restarting my session between edits. My solution works perfectly for me.

I tried all sorts of stuff, but I cannot get it to generate the error "Cannot Reference THIS-OBJECT or SUPER from a static member (15071)".

Comment: That can not working!? I can't beleave it. THIS-OBJECT reference a currently running Instance of class and THIS-OBJECT is not allowed to use in static method...

Comment: and DELETE OBJECT THIS-OBJECT work not in any case - it can't delete himself... that work realy not...

Comment: I get "Cannot Reference THIS-OBJECT or SUPER from a static member (15071)", so this doesn't work.

Comment: How strange, it works for me. I will investigate further and post an example of my implementation.

Comment: I added a fully working example to my answer. I really hope that you can reproduce the effect on your side, other wise this is going to bug me forever.

Comment: You probably just keep checking of the progress ABL or? :)

Comment: I can't compile your first class rtt/cls/demo.cls. It come the error 15071 (as expected).

Comment: But why? Why, why why? That's my next question: Why does it work for me and not for others? The coding I posted here is exactly what I tested with. I can copy and paste it directly from this page into Progress and it works for me. Of course I should be happy that it works for me, but it upsets me that I don't know why it doesn't work for you and Tim.

Comment: I'd suggest sending this to PSC Tech Support - something's different about your environment compared to ours.

Comment: I'm running 10.2B / 11.0 BTW. You might want to try downloading and installing a recent development environment and trying it in that.

Answer (score 1):

Static class elements last for the duration of the ABL session, and the only way to 'unload' them is to have a database connection go down (ie, the db server is shut down). This unloads everything, clears the client code, and leaves you in the 4GL editor.

Beyond that, the only other possible way is to create a named widget pool for the static class, then call a (static) method to delete that. I have no idea if this would work or not.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't name the pool for the static stuff, it's entirely hidden and you have no control over its creation. For the same reason, you also can't find the static "instance" of the class. You're not supposed to know that it exists. I created a static method called Reload that says "DELETE WIDGET-POOL". I was hoping that since it will run the static method in the static pool, it would delete that pool, but that did not work.

Comment: I have searched the entire interwebs and all the Progress documentation, and nowhere is there any reference of an error message 15071. A search for "Cannot Reference THIS-OBJECT or SUPER" brings up absolutely nothing but this very page. I am also unable to generate any such error. The documentation says that one cannot use THIS-OBJECT to access a static method, but no-where does it say I cannot reference THIS-OBJECT in a static method. I can find absolutely no evidence that I cannot say "DELETE OBJECT THIS-OBJECT" from a static method, And lots of proof that it works just fine.

Comment: Get the downloadable KB - it's in there: http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-104935

Comment: LOL. I am being foiled at every turn. When I follow your link, I get a page that says "UNAUTHORIZED. It appears you're not allowed to view what you requested." This is why I dislike "closed" systems like Progress. If I searched the web for an error number or part of an error message from any other language, e.g. C#, I would get hundreds of hits. I would also find references in the documentation that comes with the language. I give up. I have spent too much time on a solution that already works for me. If in 10 years time it stops working when we upgrade to a new version of Progress, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

"Static members that are scoped to the class type. This unnamed widget pool is implicitly
deleted only when the ABL session in which the widget pool is created terminates."

http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge102b/pdfs/dvoop/dvoop.pdf
page 5-9

In this case make you something wrong. You should use the static members only for methods or properties, which are realy static and must be not deleted or reinitialised when is deleted the instance of class.

when you will use it anyway, you should define your own static widget-pool with name and any static dynamic objects create in this widget-pool. then can you in Reload() write:

```
METHOD STATIC VOID Reload () :
  DELETE WIDGET-POOL XYZ.
  CREATE WIDGET-POOL XYZ.
END METHOD.
```

other way is to use a singelton class, where are defined this 'static' objects. then anytime, when you will, you can delete the instance of this singelton and make some new fresh.

Comment: Hi Firhang, thanks for answering. I know that the unnamed widget pool is implicitly deleted only when the ABL session in which the widget pool is created terminates. And I do use the static members only for methods or properties, which are really static. I know what the scope is of all the members and classes and pools that I am using. I know how to create and delete widget pools. I am using everything exactly how it is supposed to be used. Everything is perfect. My question was: how do I implement a new version (not new instance) of my class without having to restart my session.